# Validating non-string datatypes in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, localization

Imagine you have two fields in your Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateRequired"]
  public DateTime Date;

  [DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "NumberError")]
  public decimal Number;
}
```

My problem is this: If the user enters a non-valid Date (like 'aaa') or a non-valid Number (like 'bbb') then the standard jQuery validation messages kicks in like: 'The field Number must be a number' (and the same goes for Date).

How do I get a localized error message for my fields? I know I can convert my fields to strings and then manually convert these fields to my corresponding database fields, but I believe there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the correct "messages_##.js" file for your language. For instance, when I need brazilian portuguese validation, I use:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ptbr.js

Just replace "ptbr" at the end with your localization code. Of course, you can just get the code and use your own messages.

Comment: I see what you mean, but would like to be able to customize the messages 100% from C#. But it migth be that your solution is the one and only.

Comment: Since these messages are read directly from the jQuery Validate plugin, there really is no other way. They are hard-coded, right here: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L267

Comment: @JanKratochvil Yeah, I posted a link to the `master` branch before. Here is the permanent link: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/e5f2d29f571106b5ffccb20815a3624eba4286d8/src/core.js#L292.